# MySQL DATEDIFF usin DATE_ADD interval result

Tags: mysql, datediff, dateadd

im pretty new at sql, any hellp willbe deeply appreciated. i have this query:

```
Colocacion,----> DATE field --
plazo,---->INT field --
```

i add both fields

```
DATE_ADD(colocacion,INTERVAL plazo DAY)
```

adds boths colocacion and plazo, plazo is the interval, which gives me the

result=

```
vencimiento,----> DATE field,
```

it´s a due date

i add the next line to have a sort of countdown, substracting (vencimiento the result from the previous operation), my duedate, from Now

```
DATEDIFF(vencimiento, NOW()) AS countdown ---->int
```

this works ok if i manually enter the duedate, and the above last line gives me the amuount of days from now till the due date,
but if i get the duedate from the dateadd operation, even when i see the duedate on the form it doesnt showup in the datediff, so no countdown.

tks in advance

Comment: Do not use "schemes", show formatted CREATE TABLE script(s) and INSERT INTO with sample data, queries texts, received and desired outputs as formatted tables...

Comment: ok im sorry im new at this ill do it asap